# Prevent full file path on chrome console while debugging Ionic local host in Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, console, console.log, ionic3

Every time I do a `console.log()` while debugging my Ionic application the console shows me the absolute file path of the file instead of the relative to the root of my project.

for example If I do `console.log("test")` I become:

> test
>   C:/Users/myUser/Documents/TestProjects/Ionic/3/myProject/src/pages/page-list/my-page.ts:59

It makes really hard to read the console, is there a way to prevent this and just show the filename or relative path?

When I work with Mac OS this does not happen, just the file name is showed.

Thanks

Comment: +1 this is really annoying. If I'm right, this is a new feature from the last Chrome update, they also changed the error/warning filter system that is also annoying.